# Auto Screenshot of remote server using VBS

Tags: windows, vbscript, screenshot

I have tried to capture screenshot of a remote server with mentioned code but a weird things is happening. I have open CMD, application and folder to run the VBS. just folder and CMD were capture in screenshot and desktop ICON and application window were not capture. Like we see in horror movie image of ghost can't be captures :P

Please advise me what can be done. The actual problem is In my remote server a tool runs 24x7 some time it throws error and stand as it is until restarted manually. I cannot check the remote server so frequently so I thought that if I cant get screenshot in mail that will help me.

NOTE: Please stick to VBS as I can't download any external or files. This is required for official work. The code works on local system. I am facing problem with remote application server.

```
dim filesys , Imagepath
Imagepath="C:\Users\Documents\"
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
If filesys.FileExists(Imagepath & "Img.jpg") Then 
    filesys.DeleteFile Imagepath & "Img.jpg" 
    'Wscript.echo "File deleted" 
End If 

Set oWordBasic = CreateObject("Word.Basic")
oWordBasic.SendKeys "{prtsc}" 
oWordBasic.AppClose "Microsoft Word"
Set oWordBasic = Nothing
WScript.Sleep 300
set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "mspaint"
WScript.Sleep 300
WshShell.AppActivate "untitled - Paint"
WScript.Sleep 300
WshShell.SendKeys "^v"
WScript.Sleep 300
WshShell.SendKeys "^s"
WScript.Sleep 300
WshShell.SendKeys Imagepath & "Img" & ".jpg"
WScript.Sleep 300
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Sleep 300
WshShell.SendKeys "%{F4}"
Set WshShell=Nothing
```

Comment: Just curious... Why not task scheduler execute based on an event to just email when a service is down or if an event is triggered that could indicate this failure... or have the script pull some SQL data and compile an explanation outlining the issue. Curious on what data is in the screen shot that you couldn't gather with the script instead of using a UI.